# why the cookies of cookieManager is differenet from cookies of httpClient In Android?

Tags: java, android, cookies

I'm writing a program for Android that sends some `POST` to a webService with  `HttpClient` like this :

```
      DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/service");
          List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
         // Execute HTTP Post Request
      ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
      String response = httpclient.execute(httppost , responseHandler) ;
```

And I tried to retrieve a cookie of  "www.example.com" called "Form" like this:

```
             `
    Log.d("Cookie0" , httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies().get(0).getValue()) ;              
    Log.d("Cookie1", CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie("http://example.com"));
```

but the two methods of retrieving a cookie returns two different values for "Form" !
why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html) `CookieManager` is used for cookies in WebViews:

> Manages the cookies used by an application's WebView instances

So if you want to get the cookie from your request `httpclient.getCookieStore()` should be the right way.